# Delete nth node from both beginning and end of singly linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list, pseudocode

I'm just starting to learn linkedlist.

I can come up with an approach to delete a nth node from the beginning and end separately but I couldn't take care of the checks needed to perform both at the same time.

**Delete nth node from both beginning and end**

**INPUT:**

```
1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9->10->NULL
N =4
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1->2->3->5->6->8->9->10->NULL
```

DELETE FROM BEGINNING :

```
void deletePosition(struct Node** head, int n){
struct Node* temp = *head;
struct Node* previous;

int size=0;

while(node!=NULL){
    node = node->next;
    size++;
}

if(n < 1 || n > size){
    return;
}

if(n == 1){
    *head = (*head)->next;
    free(temp);
    return;
}

while (--n) 
{
    previous = temp; 
    temp = temp->next; 
}
previous->next = temp->next;

free(temp);
```

}

DELETE FROM THE END :

```
    Node* deleteNode(Node* head, int key)
{
    Node* temp;
    Node* first = head;
    Node* second = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < key; i++) {
        if (second->next == NULL) {
            if (i == key - 1) {
                temp = head;
                head = head->next;
                free(temp);
            }
            return head;
        }
        second = second->next;
    }
 
    while (second->next != NULL) {
        first = first->next;
        second = second->next;
    }
 
    temp = first->next;
    first->next = first->next->next;
    free(temp);
    return head;
}
```

general algorithm or pseudo code would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are your own efforts? SO is not a code writing service...

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same time"? You can delete the nth node. Then delete the first, then find the last and delete that too..

Comment: Take a pencil and some paper. Draw the list as you just did in your question. Draw the pointers (arrows) that you need to delete the node. Try to figure out how to do this using the pencil and paper first.

Comment: @Jayaram18 In C++ indices start from 0 not from 1.

Comment: *'General algorithm'* depends on the data structure you use for your linked list (doubly linked, with both head and tail pointer or just one of, ...). You should provide a [mre].

Comment: As for deleting from the end, try reversing the list and see what happens.

Comment: If I first delete the nth from beginning and then pass the linkedlist to a function which deletes n-1 instead of n, if n is greater than mid value , will it work ?

Comment: Assuming a singly linked list: Move with a first pointer n steps in your list; this is the node from the beginning; then have a second pointer starting as copy of the first and a third starting at the list's beginning. Move second and third in parallel (equal number of steps) until second one reaches the list's end. Third pointer now points to the node from the end. Make sure you have the nodes' predecessors available, too, then you can safely delete both nodes found.

Comment: Side note: Be aware that the node from the end might be in front of from the beginning if `n` is large enough, and especially both might be the same point. You'll likely need some special handling for.

Comment: @Aconcagua everybody else in this thread seem to be missing this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you are at node 3.

```
helper = this -> next -> next;
delete this -> next;
this -> next = helper;
```

So basically you need to get to the node after the one you seek to delete prior to that deletion as then there will be no way of accessing it.

To check if there are any nodes at all:

```
if(root == NULL)
{
 /// there are no nodes
}
```

If there are nodes:

```
traverse = root;
int count = 0;
while(traverse != NULL)
{
   ++count;
   if(count == n)
   { /* you are at the nth node */ }
   traverse = traverse -> next;
}
```

Notice that if you delete node n and you are still at node (n-1), you will just have to do a seperate "shift of indicies," so to say, to remove another node. So if you want to delete another node that was previously the pth one, then just do in the if statement

```
///the deletion
++count;
```

Effectively you will get count == p when you arrive at the node that was the pth one until any deletions.

Comment: I'd assume the question author knows how to delete a single node once it is found – and question is rather about how to find these two nodes to delete.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I'm fine with deletion from both beginning and end when n is less than mid value. I've confusion when n is greater than mid value and I would like to know the efficient way to solve this, rather than simply decrementing n to n-1 for the sake of removing 1 node.

Comment: Fixed my answer again, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: This is exactly what I could think of. Thanks for your input. Is there any other way to achieve this ? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could do a list with pointers to every second element of the original list, another one with pointers to every second element  of the new list, and so on. This could speed up the process of searching.

Answer (score 1):

The task is not simple for such beginners as you and me.

Nevertheless, we, beginners, should help each other.

For starters indices in C++ start from 0.

Secondly you should check whether the pointer starting from the tail is equal to the pointer starting from the head. Or whether one pointer is the pointer of the data member next of the node pointed to by other pointer.

For example if the two pointers are equal each other you need to delete only one node in the list.

I can not write a pseudo code. It is too complicated for me.
So here you are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <functional>

struct ListNode
{
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
};


void clear( ListNode * &head )
{
    while (head)
    {
        delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
    }
}

void create( ListNode *&head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    clear( head );

    for (ListNode **current = &head; n--; current = &( *current )->next)
    {
        *current = new ListNode{ *a++, nullptr };
    }
}

std::ostream &display( const ListNode *head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for (const ListNode *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
    {
        os << current->val << " -> ";
    }

    return os << "null";
}

void swap( ListNode *&current )
{
    if (current && current->next)
    {
        ListNode *&next = current->next;
        std::swap( current, next );
        std::swap( current->next, next->next );
        swap( next );
    }
}

bool remove_two_sides_n( ListNode * &head, size_t n )
{
    ListNode **left = &head;

    while (*left && n--) left = &( *left )->next;

    if (*left == nullptr) return false;

    ListNode **right = &head;
    ListNode *last = *left;

    while (last->next)
    {
        right = &( *right )->next;
        last = last->next;
    }


    if (( *right )->next == *left) std::swap( left, right );

    if ( right != left )
    {
        ListNode *tmp = *right;
        *right = ( *right )->next;
        delete tmp;
    }

    ListNode *tmp = *left;
    *left = ( *left )->next;
    delete tmp;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 9;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N + 1; i++)
    {
        ListNode *head = nullptr;
        const int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        create( head, a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

        std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << i << ": ";
        display( head ) << '\n';

        remove_two_sides_n( head, i );

        std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << i << ": ";
        display( head ) << '\n';

        clear( head );

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
 0: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
 0: 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> null

 1: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
 1: 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 9 -> null

 2: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
 2: 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 8 -> 9 -> null

 3: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
 3: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null

 4: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
 4: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null

 5: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
 5: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null

 6: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
 6: 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 8 -> 9 -> null

 7: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
 7: 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 9 -> null

 8: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
 8: 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> null

 9: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
 9: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

Comment: Nice move to include case N=5 where there is only one node removed!

Comment: @Jayaram18  As for me then the assignment is very interesting. I upvoted your question.